# Change values of row to be NaN - Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

i have a 2D array 
i want to change values of  some row  in the array to be NaN

```
array = 
[[ 1 2 3]
[2 4 5]
[5 6 7]]
```

change_values_row_nan(array, [2])

```
[[ 1 2 3]
[2 4 5]
[nan nan nan]]
```

change_values_row_nan(array, [0,2])

```
[[nan nan nan]
[2 4 5]
[nan nan nan]]
```

how to do this ?

Comment: Try `array[[0, 2]] = np.nan`?

Comment: Your example array is of type integer by default. However, there's no `NaN` integer. You'll have to use type `float` or `object` (as oppressionslayer shows in his answer). Refer to [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) on how to change values along certain axes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3], 
[2 ,4, 5], 
[5, 6, 7]], dtype=object) 

a[0] = np.NaN
```

output:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [2, 4, 5],
       [5, 6, 7]], dtype=object)
```

or

```
a[0::2] = np.nan                                                                                                                                                                    

a
```

```
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [2, 4, 5],
       [nan, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```